# How get position of table row in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to show a rectangle around the tables row when user click on them, but the top and left property return nothing. my code:

styles of focusRect:

```
  #focusRect {
            position:absolute;
            visibility: visible;
            border: 2px solid red;
        }

   <script type="text/javascript">

        function moveFocus(obj) {
            var fr = document.getElementById("focusRect");

            fr.style.top = obj.style.top+"px";
            fr.style.left = obj.style.left+"px";
            fr.style.width = obj.offsetWidth+"px";
            fr.style.height = obj.offsetHeight+"px";
        }
    </script>
```

and on tables tr tag:

```
<tr onclick="moveFocus(this)">

 <div id="focusRect"></div>
```

NOTE: I not write unnecessary codes here

Comment: Why are you not using CSS `border` or `outline` directly on the `tr`?

Comment: Maybe write in pseudo code what result you would like to get. Something to work to.

Comment: Also please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <td>Click to show rowIndex</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <td>Click to show rowIndex</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <td>Click to show rowIndex</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <td>Click to show rowIndex</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
function myFunction(x) {
  console.log("Row index is: " + x.rowIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"#" this is a class. It is not an element or id. It is used for styling for your css page. To set the id you can do this in HTML or javascript.
html:

```
id="fname"
```

javascript:

```
let text = document.createElement('p'); 
//notice that you are assigning this element to "text" and then setting it's id.
text.id = "cellText";
```

So lets say you set the id to "focusRect" and assigned it to "rectang" (so `let = document.getElementById("focusRect")` then you can refer to the object through rectang each time. (It would be helpful for you to look up dom: document object model).

```
rectang.style.border = "thick solid #0000FF";
```